# Clean Up AWS Resources using AWS-Nuke for a Cognito User?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an application where I am using

- Cognito User Pool
- Identity Pool
- Custom URL to give access to Console

I want to delete the resources created by that Cognito User automatically after a session of 1 hour,

I tried with AWS-Nuke but I am not able to automate it for dynamic users, it works for the whole account. Can anybody suggest how to do it?

Comment: You can filter that user in the Cloud Trail using python, can be a lambda function and finally apply terminate/ delete action to nuke that up.

Comment: Can you help me with some reference of HOW TO?